# Fullcalendar revertFunc() + dragRevertDuration

Tags: fullcalendar

When manually rejecting an event drop with Fullcalendars 'revertFunc()', it seems that the 'dragRevertDuration' option, as set when constructing the calendar, is not used (contrary to reversions when an event is dragged/dropped on e.g. an other event when overlap = false). Is it possible to use the 'revertFunc()' with the 'dragRevertDuration'?

Fullcalendar Docs (+ dragRevertDuration property)

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        // events here
    ],
    editable: true,
    dragRevertDuration: 1000,
    eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {
        if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
            revertFunc();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you're mistaking the parameter for drop event, its not the same as resize event

Try this parameter this works fine for me : (for drop and resize event)

if this one not working then check the parameter,

(I'm using version FullCalendar v1.5.4)

```
eventDrop: function(event, dayDelta, minuteDelta, allDay, revertFunc) {
   alert("Move Event : "+event.title+" to "+event.start);

   if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
      revertFunc();
   }else{
      console.log(event);
      alert(event.title + " end is now " + event.end);
   }        
},
eventResize: function(event, delta, allDay, revertFunc) {
   alert(event.title + " end is now " + event.end);
   if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
      revertFunc();
   }
},
```